# Questions about energy-audit services on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently had an energy audit done on my house by a national contractor, who offer this service in many cities around the country.  Would it be on-topic to ask about the general validity of these audits and about others' experiences with these audits?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think so.

Comment: I agree that discussing the results of an energy audit (or even how to go about getting one done) would be on topic.